# Problemas con las urls de Juniper

Tags: angular

Tengo una aplicación con Angular 9 pero no funciona por la zona de seguridad ya que tenemos implantado Juniper. He intentado poner un Interceptor pero no ha funcionado.

¿Alguien puede decirme en donde estoy fallando?

gracias

Este es mi interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


declare function DanaUrl(url: string): string;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DanaHttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if ( typeof DanaUrl === 'function' && !request.url.includes( '.html' ) ) {
      request = request.clone({
        url: DanaUrl( request.url )
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Comment: Qué funcionalidad de tu aplicación falla debido al Juniper? Podrías pedir que se revisen los logs del Juniper; es un equipo con una gran cantidad de políticas, que puede filtrar peticiones por numerosos criterios y validaciones (lo sufrí hace un tiempo porque filtraba los GET con más de N argumentos en el query, es realmente poderoso en el análisis de las peticiones)

Comment: Hola AlfaBravo. Gracias por tu respuesta. Realmente la página no renderiza. Se queda en blanco. Saludos